# Vimscript save file

Tags: vimscript

I am making a function to compile and run my application. I have been able to get it to run the shell command however I cannot get it to save the file.

Here is my code so far.

Try 1)

```
function Compile_and_run(game, major, minor)
    :w <CR>
    execute '!_compile' shellescape(a:game) shellescape(a:major) shellescape(a:minor)
endfunction
```

Try 2)

```
function Compile_and_run(game, major, minor)
    execute ":w <CR>"
    execute '!_compile' shellescape(a:game) shellescape(a:major) shellescape(a:minor)
endfunction
```

What is it that Im doing wrong? How would I get this function to save before the `execute '!_compile'` command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like `:w<CR>` makes sense for creating a Normal mode mapping. In Normal mode, you need the `:` to enter Command-line mode, and the `<CR>` to execute the command and return to Normal mode.

### Writing VimScript

Here, since you're writing VimScript, every line is interpreted as if it's in Command-line mode already. You don't need to lead with a `:` (though it's harmless if you do), and you don't need the `<CR>` to execute the command (and in this case, it's incorrect to use it).

You only need `write` (or `w` for short) in this context.

```
function Compile_and_run(game, major, minor)
    write
    execute '!_compile' shellescape(a:game) shellescape(a:major) shellescape(a:minor)
endfunction
```

Take a look at [`:help vim-script-intro`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#vim-script-intro) to learn more.